# How to set .vcxproj to let MSBuild compile a dll

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, compilation, msbuild

**Above All**

To save your time from reading a lot, Thanks to CristiFati and here is the answer:
If you use "Library" in "ConfigurationType" like me, you'll get an .obj file instead of .dll.
The right keyword is "DynamicLibrary" instead of "Library". That is:

```
<ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
```

Then you'll have the .dll you want.

[supplement] From CMake Documents, thanks to Botje's guiding, it appears that a "Library" is actually like a sub-directory under the root project. Thus it's different with how dll work.

---

**Short Story**:

- I need to compile a dll with MSbuild, without any IDE.
- I followed instruction on Microsoft Doc to create app build project.
- No webpage indicates how to create dll build project is found yet. Thus I edit .vcxproj according to similar google info.
- BUILD SUCCESS!
- But the result only contain a .obj file. No dll in sight.
- Need help about how to modify a .vcxproj to build a dll.

---

**Detailed Story**:

I need to compile a dll.
My company didn't buy any commercial license thus I cannot use any IDE for this.

However MSBuild is safe to use.
I'm following this page to create a C++ project which could be compiled with MSBuild only.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-using-msbuild-to-create-a-visual-cpp-project?view=vs-2017
You don't need actually read that page because I'll paste the project file below.

First, Following that page, I got this application type project file

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Debug|Win32">
      <Configuration>Debug</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="helloworld.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="helloworld.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
</Project>
```

I tested the build. And got my .exe file successfully. And my helloworld.exe printed "HelloWorld" as predicted. Then...
Second, Following this page:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp?view=vs-2017
I'm sure the header and cpp file is good to go

```
#pragma once

#ifdef HELLOWORLD_EXPORTS
#define HELLOWORLD_API __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define HELLOWORLD_API __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

extern "C" HELLOWORLD_API void helloworld();
```

Third, Switch this project from application mode to library mode...
Actually I'm not sure how to do this. So I googled some info and try to do what they did.
I change the Debug mode to Release mode.
Then change the Application output to Library.

```
<Project DefaultTargets="Build" ToolsVersion="15.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <ProjectConfiguration Include="Release|Win32">
      <Configuration>Release</Configuration>
      <Platform>Win32</Platform>
    </ProjectConfiguration>
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.default.props" />
  <PropertyGroup>
    <ConfigurationType>Library</ConfigurationType>
    <PlatformToolset>v141</PlatformToolset>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.props" />
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClCompile Include="helloworld.cpp" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <ItemGroup>
    <ClInclude Include="helloworld.h" />
  </ItemGroup>
  <Import Project="$(VCTargetsPath)\Microsoft.Cpp.Targets" />
</Project>
```

Finally, I let msbuild do its work:

```
msbuild helloworld.vcxproj /p:configuration=Release
```

And the build is success!

But when I head to Release folder under my root directory, I find only a "helloworld.obj" file and a "vc141.pdb" along a folder names "helloworld.tlog".
Well this is not right. I think the right result will be a "helloworld.dll" in here.

So, that should be my .vcxproj file's problem I guess.
So, could anybody kindly give a guide for creating a dll project from scratch?
Thanks!

Comment: Are you using the visual studio build tools to compile? Iirc they are distributed under the same license as visual studio. If you cannot use the community edition because your company is too big, you need a license for the IDE anyway to use the build tools.

Comment: Given that you're not using an IDE, have you considered writing your build script in Cmake? It can generate visual studio projects that you can build with msbuild (or ninja projects, or makefiles).

Comment: @Botje WAT? MSBuild tool is same? hmm... Yeah if so, I'll have to give up this tho. I'll try CMake then. I see CMake says it is open source.

Comment: @Botje It says... CMake doesn't build the final program directly. CMake only produce the relay file like Makefile in Unix and projects in VCBuild. So, does it means that I still must have a license for Visual Studio? Do we have any open-sourced compiler available? Difficulty and learning is not a problem. Thanks

Comment: Mingw has been around forever as a toolchain that ships gcc for windows. Clang is the new contender that is endorsed by Microsoft (yet free)

Comment: @Botje Ah! I found the GCC! CMake plus GCC and I think I'm good to go! Thank you very much for the direction. (This post will be deleted tomorrow as it is already left its topic)

Comment: The project type should be ***Dynamic**Library*: `<ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>`.

Comment: @CristiFati That's it! DynamicLibrary will work. Thank you for your help and sorry for the late reply. Could you please give this as an answer so I can apply it? Although I have to give up the MSBuild because the license problem but maybe others will need this help.

Comment: I am glad you have got your solution and thanks for your sharing, I would appreciate it if you mark them as answer and this will be beneficial to other community.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although using the *IDE* is prohibited by licensing purposes, listing [[MS.Docs]: Walkthrough: Create and use your own Dynamic Link Library (C++)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/walkthrough-creating-and-using-a-dynamic-link-library-cpp) anyway.

The keypoint is:

> *3*. From the filtered list of project types, select **Dynamic-link Library (DLL)**, and then choose **Next**.

Behind the scenes, that maps to: [[MS.Docs]: ConfigurationTypes Enum](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.visualstudio.vcproject.configurationtypes):

> **Fields**
>
> typeApplication             1      Application (.exe)
>
> typeDynamicLibrary      2      Dynamic Library (.dll)
>
> typeGeneric                 10      Makefile, displays makefile toolset (NMake)
>
> typeStaticLibrary           4      Static Library (.dll)
>
> typeUnknown                0      Utility

Translated to *.vcxproj* structure, the *ConfigurationType* node:

```xml
<ConfigurationType>Application</ConfigurationType>
```

should be converted to:

```xml
<ConfigurationType>DynamicLibrary</ConfigurationType>
```

But, as (@Botje's) comments rightly pointed out, you should move towards free build tools (there are a number of alternatives, and *CMake* seems to be the best one).

Comment: Thanks. Actually I already move to GCC + CMake combination since I was told that VS Build Tool is requiring a license. Those are open-sourced thus I could simply use them without complex paperwork in company. GCC and CMake makes me confused a bit at the beginning. But we are good to go after get familiar with them.